# PHP + MySQL taking a 3rd variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a C# code and a PHP that gets info I send from C#.
So I need to have such code:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
$database = mysqli_select_db($link,'serial');

$serial = $_GET['serial'];
$hwid = $_GET['hwidin'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM serial WHERE serial = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$serial) ."'" ;
$result = $link->query($sql);

/*
0 = Wrong HWID
1 = HWID is correct
2 = HWID left empty
3 = No serial with that key
*/

if(strlen($hwid) < 1)
{
    echo "2";
}
else
{
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if (strlen($row['hwid']) > 1)
            {
                if ($hwid != $row['hwid'])
                {
                    echo "0";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "1";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $sql = "UPDATE serial SET hwid='$hwid' WHERE serial='$serial'";
                echo "1";
                if(mysqli_query($link, $sql))
                {
                    echo $row['hwid'];
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "3";
    }
}
```

So what I want to do is add some checking, for example:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if (strlen($row['hwid']) > 1)
        {
            if ($hwid != $row['hwid'])
            {
                echo "0"; 
            }
            else
            {
                echo "1";
            }

            If echo "1" {
                $sql = "SELECT time FROM serial Where serial = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$serial) ."'" ;
                $result = $link->query($sql);

                if $result > 1 {
                    echo "55";
                }
```

I need somehow to combine it with hwid checker and serial checker.
I want to check "time" column variable and use > < 1 to decide what to echo.

Comment: If's should be in parentheses, and echo does not have a return value. If you want to check the echo "1", do it right after it is echoed in the else. The result is a resource, it can't really be compared to a number.

Comment: Hm i got it, so what i want actually do is to get a variable from "time" column (but check the hwid before, and choose the time from this one column ) and recieve a php $variable to do some >1 check and do echo after that

Comment: I get it, but you are doing it at the completly wrong place, and a completly wrong way. (A quick question, you have never used a programming language before, right?) When you check the $hwid, the correct result will already be in the else part. You can copy the first part of your second if there: `else { echo "1"; $sql = [...]; $result = [...]; if (part of result with something) { do something} }`

Comment: Just decided to let this cicle finish and add some new variables below and check the column "time" for variable where hwid = $hwid . Then i wll just create some kind of $variable to compare if it's > 1 and do echo .

Comment: hm thanks for your idea, i will test it for sure if i get it right, No, i just did some php work like 10 years ago . i dont actually remember it. And need to learn it again because of some things changed.